# Make google logo always on top - Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, graphical-logo

I need to set the Google Maps logo always on top, as it is needed by Google policy. I tried everything I found there on stack Overflow but could not find the right way. I did managed to remove the logo, but I am struggling with placing it on very top.

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps API Terms of Service prohibits any modification of the logo or other attribution, you should show it as it was provided by default.

Please have a look at paragraph 9.4 (a) of ToS:

> Content provided to you through the Service may contain the Brand Features of Google, its strategic partners, or other third-party rights holders of content that Google indexes. When Google provides those Brand Features or other attribution through the Service, you **must display such attribution as provided** (or as described in the Maps APIs Documentation) and must not delete or alter the attribution.

https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_9_4

Comment: Well I known deleting the logo is against policy, but setting it on very top of everything should be allowed in my opinion. Because I want it to be visible. After two hours I was able to move the map and show the logo(I have navbar at the right side)

Comment: I think ToS is pretty clear with words 'must not alter the attribution'.